# Can i allow users to edit word and visio documents from the document library and publish them again

Tags: document-library, publishing-site, office-integration, word, visio

I am working on a publishing site collection, and I have a document library which contains Microsoft Word and Microsoft Visio files. Is there a way to allow users to do the following :

1. Select a document from the SharePoint document library.
2. Click on Edit.
3. Open the document using their client program either Word or Visio.
4. Modify the document contents.
5. Directly publish the new file to the SharePoint document library
   again?

Can anyone advise if this is possible? When I try this from my machine, there is no option inside the Word document or inside Visio to publish to SharePoint. I can only save the document locally and not on the SharePoint server.
Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "Publish" you just save the document and it will default to the source Library. If they edit it in the browser it will save back to the Library as well. The user has to have sufficient permissions to perform the task, in this case they need Edit rights.

Comment: i do not have the requires services to edit word documents inside the browsers. i am talking about opening the word document by clicking on it from the document library, then after the documents opens inside the client application, they can click on "Edit document" button, modify the word content , click on "Save" button, which will automatically updates the SharePoint document library ? is this what u mean? and what is i user select the document and click on "Edit" button which is shown inside the SharePoint document library, can he follow the same steps ?

Comment: Depending on your configuration the "Edit" button may or may not show. Clicking Save (or Save As) will save the document back to the library. Clicking Edit in Word (or Visio) from he ECB (drop down menu) will Open the document in the client application as well.

Comment: so if the user open the word document using his client application (by clicking on the document from the sharepoint library)and he modify the document , then he clicks on save . then will he be able to save the changes to SharePoint even if he does not have the required permissions ?

Comment: No, if he does not have edit permissions he will not be able to save the document back to SharePoint.